# Time complexity of testing if a binary tree is balanced

Tags: java, time-complexity, binary-tree

The code below tests whether a binary tree is balanced. I have been told that its running time is O(n log n).

To my understanding...

- `getHeight()` visits every node once, so it is O(n).
- `isBalanced()` calls `getHeight()`.. then recurse

If `isBalanced()` is called on all n nodes, and it calls `getHeight()` which is O(n), why isn't the complexity O(n²)?

```
int getHeight(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return -1; 
    return Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right)) + 1;
}

boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return true;
    int heightDiff = getHeight(root.left) - getHeight(root.right);
    if (Math.abs(heightDiff) > 1) 
        return false;
    else
        return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);

}
```

Comment: What you said is true but incomplete. Recurse how many times?

Comment: would recursing isBalanced() not visit every node in tree as well?

Comment: Please trave through the code and see

Comment: The recursive method is called on every node in the worst case, when the tree is balanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By n, you mean the number of nodes in the whole tree. In that case, the `getHeight` method is only O(n) when you call it on the root node. In general, it is O(m) where m is the number of nodes in the subtree of the node you call `getHeight` on; and most of those subtrees are a lot smaller than n. This is the root cause of your confusion.

The `isBalanced` method returns early, without recursing, when the left and right subtrees differ in height by 2 or more. So we only need to count recursive calls for the nodes with left and right heights differing by at most 1, i.e. nodes whose subtrees are balanced. In the worst case, all nodes' subtrees are balanced so we never get to stop recursing early.

Given that, let's assume the tree *is* balanced. Then `getHeight` is called once per node, and has a running time proportional to the size of the node's subtree. For a balanced tree of size n = 2^k - 1, there are:

- 2^(k-1) leaf nodes whose subtree size is 1,
- 2^(k-2) subtrees of size 3,
- 2^(k-3) subtrees of size 7,
- ...
- 2^i subtrees of size 2^(k-i) - 1,
- ...
- 2 subtrees of size 2^(k-1) - 1,
- 1 subtree of size 2^k - 1 = n.

The sum of these is the sum for i = 0 to k-1 of 2^i * (2^(k-i) - 1). Each term is approximately 2^k = n, and there are k = log_2 n terms, giving a total complexity of n * log_2 n = O(n log n).